# Enable SEDE graph image to be saved or copied

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, images, graphs

When graphing data on SEDE, eg [this example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/535639/#graph), right-clicking on the image and selecting either "Save as file" or "Copy image" both result in a totally black rectangle (albeit of the correct dimensions) being saved/copied.

Is there a way enable the displayed graph to be saved/copied (ie to work "as expected by the user")?

Comment: Screenshot? That's my go to way.

Comment: @bluefeet yeah, that's what I used too. But is that the best we can do?

Comment: I agree the idea, so +1. But: until it is implemented, you can make a screenshot from your browser window and then postprocess it with anything.

Comment: It needs this [trickery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616925/save-flot-graph-as-image). I use the Fireshot plugin in Chrome btw to capture the graphs on my SEDE queries.